# What's the difference between $user login and access?

Tags: 7, users

I'm migrating users and I came across the [$user object](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7).

What's the difference between the login and access field? Does access get updated with every page request?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *access* field is updated in Drupal's session write handler [_drupal_session_write](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/_drupal_session_write/7). This means it is potentially updated at every page request. If you look at the source code, you'll see that the *access* field is, by default, only updated every 180 seconds. This interval can be changed by setting the `session_write_interval` Drupal variable.

```
// Likewise, do not update access time more than once per 180 seconds.
if ($user->uid && REQUEST_TIME - $user->access > variable_get('session_write_interval', 180)) {
  db_update('users')
    ->fields(array(
    'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  ))
    ->condition('uid', $user->uid)
    ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

According to the the comments for the fields in [`user_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.install/function/user_schema/7):

`access`: Timestamp for previous time user accessed the site.

`login`: Timestamp for user’s last login.

So `access` would get updated for each page load, `login` only when the user actually logged in.