# Show if a user is online, idle, or offline on their account page?

Tags: 8, theming, users

I want to display the status of the user on the account page. I added the following code in the theme I am using. It works, but users are never displayed offline.

Why? What is wrong in the code?

#### user.html.twig

```
<div class="bs-field-status">
  {% if status == 'Online' %}
    <i class="user-online fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Online
  {% elseif status == 'Absent' %}
    <i class="user-absent fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Absent
  {% else %}
    <i class="user-offline fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Offline
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

#### bootstrap_subtheme_front_office.theme

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Bootstrap sub-theme.
 *
 * Place your custom PHP code in this file.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  // get user object
  $user = $variables['elements']['#user'];
  //- The user has logged in at least once
  if ($user->getLastLoginTime()) {
    if (account_is_logged_in_less_then_thirty_minutes($user->id())) {
      $status = 'Online';
    }
    else {
      $status = 'Absent';
    }
  }
  else {
    $status = 'Offline';
  }
  $variables['status'] = $status;
}

/**
 * @param $uid
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function account_is_logged_in_less_then_thirty_minutes($uid) {
  $connection = Database::getConnection();
  $query = $connection->select('sessions', 'sessions')
    ->fields('sessions', ['sid', 'uid', 'timestamp'])
    ->condition('sessions.uid', $uid, '=')
    //- chef if the user was online in 30 minutes (60 * 30)
    ->condition('sessions.timestamp', \Drupal::time()
        ->getRequestTime() - (60 * 30), '>')
    ->execute();
  //- Get result.
  $results = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  return (count($results) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I think that the biggest issue here is cache. If you need some realtime info a preprocess hook shouldn't be the way to go. Instead I'd recommend to expose an explicitly uncached custom route that takes a uid as argumemt, and then returns a JSON response built from a callback that holds your code. And finally add some JS to your site that requests that route and places the outcome somewhere in your markup.

Comment: @leymannx Thank you. I am not looking for a specific status. If there is a shift of 3 minutes it is OK

Comment: What's been done in a preprocess hook normally is cached until you flush the Drupal cache for the next time if you don't implement some kind of a cache busting logic.

Comment: If you don't do it the AJAX way you'll need to add something like `$variables['#cache']['max-age'] = strtotime('+3 minutes');` in the preprocess hook, switch off the page cache module, and make sure any reverse proxy sitting in front of the site is configured to react. You might find the AJAX route to be less of a bother in the end

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem lies here, for starters:

```
//- The user has logged in at least once
  if ($user->getLastLoginTime()) {
    if (account_is_logged_in_less_then_thirty_minutes($user->id())) {
      $status = 'Online';
    }
    else {
      $status = 'Absent';
    }
  }
  else {
    $status = 'Offline';
  }
```

The `if ($user->getLastLoginTime()) {` will be TRUE always, after the user has logged in once. This will prevent the `else` from ever being hit, thus, 'Offline' never gets set.

I don't know what the difference is for you in terms of time between "Absent" or "Offline", but it sounds like you'd want to figure another calculation here to know what to set status to.

This can be simplified to:

```
function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  // get user object
 $user = $variables['elements']['#user'];

 $last = $user->getLastAccessedTime();
 $now = \Drupal::time()->getRequestTime();

 switch ($last) {
   case ($last > ($now - 900)) :
     $variables['status'] = 'Online';
     break;
   case (($last < ($now - 900)) && $last > ($now - 1800)) :
     $variables['status'] = 'Absent';
     break;
   default:
     $variables['status'] = 'Offline';
     break;
 }
}
```

Then break down smaller functions to evaulate the time against how many minutes ago they were active... use it in the switch above.

`getLastAccessedTime()` does:

> The timestamp when the account last accessed the site.
>
> A value of 0 means the user has never accessed the site.

So you don’t need a `db_select`.

Comment: I am trying to put the user `absent` after 15 minutes of inactivity and `offline` after 30 minutes of inactivity (or when disconnected)

Comment: With the access value can we do 3 status? from 0 to 15 minutes "online", from 15 to 30 minustes "absent" (means unavailable), 30 minutes superior "offline".

Comment: The access value is the timestamp when the account last accessed the site according to the documentation. I don't know how frequently it is written to.

Comment: So fill in the blanks, this is just boilerplate code.

Comment: This answer here proves that its the method you want, not the last login time: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/21873/57

Comment: From the initial question? Yes... that is the method you should use to get the last access timestamp of a user. You just fill in the parts that does the math of _how long ago_ that time was, in order to know which status to set.

Comment: You don't need the `account_is_logged_in_less_then_thirty_minutes` function at all because the `getLastAccessedTime` method gives you the timestamp of when the user last accessed the site.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean at this point. I even filled in the time calculation.

Comment: What happens if the duration is equal to 900 seconds ?

Comment: Then use >=, I’m not going to code out every scenario for you.

Comment: thank you, it works. In your answer you should replace current_status with status so that it matches the question (TWIG)

Comment: If I use this code in a custom module instead of the theme. Does this solve the problem of the cache memory ?

Comment: Hey Kevin, I found a bug in your `switch`. It needs to start with `switch (TRUE)` to work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24813225/2199525

Comment: Right, I don’t think it should be a switch now. User kept changing the context of the question and adding more, and I kept editing.

Comment: Nah, I like the switch! It's efficient, it's readable, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. (Except for the mentioned bug.)

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate problem with Drupal and user status is cache, but here is some code I am working with.

```
if ($variables['accessTime'] > (intval(time()) - 800)) {
  $variables['sessionState'] = 'active';
}
else {
  $variables['sessionState'] = 'inactive';
}
```

Then in Twig you can do stuff like:

```
{% if sessionState == active %}

{% endif %}
```

or

```
{%
  set activeClass = [
    sessionState == 'active' ? 'Active' : 'Not Active'
  ]
%}
```

Comment: Why do you need to target the page title? I don't get that? This deals with showing the users status on their account page, basically users looking at other user profiles. They're using the proper preprocess function, the code itself is not accurate.

Comment: Maybe I misread the question let me update my answer. Doesn't need to say so much anyway.

Comment: @Prestosaurus The status of the user will be displayed at several places on the site. Conversation, comment, product, store, node, group, ... wherever his name appears.
I want the code to be user with the TWIG code of my question

Comment: I think you're going to have a harder time doing that sitewide, because your cache times will decrease dramatically just to ensure you're showing an accurate status. I thought you just wanted this on their profile.

Comment: @mathmath Kind of where my mind was going. Following this question, and please see: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271119/get-last-node-access-timestamp-per-node-by-user as well as https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273350/how-to-programmatically-add-custom-markup-to-every-displayed-user-name

Comment: @kevin The code will be user only in the TWIG file of the user display (full, compact, teaser). There is no need to have updated status to the minute.

Comment: Ok, then I think my answer is still accurate. It might need some cache tag / context help beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

As Prestosaurus in their answer already said, the biggest issue here is cache. What's been done in preprocess hooks will be cached until you flush Drupal's theme cache the next time. You'll need to ensure the cache gets busted by reducing the max age of your piece of markup or by ajaxifying it completely.

---

I just created [User Online Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_online_status). This module contains a new pseudo field for user entities, a route to return a given user's online status as a non-cached JSON response, and some JS that checks that response and prints the online status into the pseudo field.

It still needs proper description, screenshots and tests, though.

1. Download and enable the module.
2. Go to http://d8.localhost/user/1 to see the online status of user 1.

Optionally: Go to http://d8.localhost/admin/config/people/accounts/display to adjust the "Online Status" field's weight.

---

Credits for the `switch` snippet to Kevin ([answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/273974/15055)).

Comment: I'll add a theme tomorrow, so everybody can create their own template to add a label or customize the markup.

Comment: This is great news, it is late I will test it tomorrow. It is obvious that drupal 8 does not include this feature in the kernel. Yet drupal has always managed users. Does your module manage the idle status ? Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should replace `case ($last > ($now - 900)):` by `case ($last >= ($now - 900)):` otherwise there will be a white at 900 seconds